# is there a modifier that can smooth geometry but keep boundary vertices position unchanged

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

Is there an modifier that can smooth out vertices while preventing its boundary vertices from moving?
What I am searching for is basically smooth modifier but with "Pin Boundaries" functionality of smooth corrective modifier.
If there is no such modifier is it possible to somehow create this functionality in geometry node?
I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp9_KqGJNrk Maybe this is what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks for helping, but what I am looking for is a modifier, not operator/ python script/ sculpt mode tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Corrective Smooth modifier with "pin boundaries" and "only smooth" enabled.  There's nothing that's really "corrective" about the modifier at that point.

Alternatively, you can create a vertex group to specify which vertices you'd like to smooth, and then designate that modifier in the vertex group field of a Smooth modifier.  So you could, for example, assign all vertices except boundary vertices to that vertex group.  (Or, assign boundary vertices, and then click the "invert" button to the right of the modifier's VG field.)

You can quickly select boundary verts via "select non-manifold" operation in edit mode, so marking verts with VGs is a perfectly reasonable way to handle this.